# how can I reduce this nested condition to one line in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am writing a little practice program to pair left and right brackets. How can I reduce the nested for/if to one line? I have tried `pure += [char for char in expression if char in brackets else '']` but it is not working. Here is the full code I want to reduce.

```
 def pair(expression):
        left=("(","[","{")
        right=(")","]","}")
        brackets=left+right
        print(brackets)
        pure=''

        #the part I want to reduce
        for char in expression:
            if char in brackets:
                pure+=char
```

Comment: `pure = ''.join([char for char in expression if char in brackets])`

Comment: what exactly does this program do btw o.O

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Rico. Your paren matcher seems to be a bit flawed.

Comment: I only posted the relevant part to the question. It was originally a forty-line-function. I really don't like posting a very long piece of code and make the answerers spend a good ten minutes looking for the lines I am talking about before they can actually answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for

```
''.join([_ if _ in brackets else '' for _ in expression])
```

Although as others have pointed out in the comments, this serves no purpose at all.

Full function

```
def pair(expression):
    left = ("(", "[", "{")
    right = (")", "]", "}")
    brackets = left + right
    print(brackets)
    pure = ''.join([_ if _ in brackets else '' for _ in expression])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why do you use `_` instead of a "proper" variable name though?

Comment: _ is a typical name for a temporary throwaway variable. It is not meant to be used anywhere beyond this line. If you name it as 'x' or 'char', you can't have another variable named 'x' or 'char' in this function after this line.

Comment: You should only use `_` for variables that you never use. Since it is used in this example, it would make the code easier to read if it was properly named. Sometime it is a good idea to name unused variables anyway if it would make the code easier to understand to you or others later.